# How to access workspace Office 365 Connector Webhook URL in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, notifications, office365, microsoft-teams

Each worskspace has its own Office 365 Connector Notification Webhook:
[image]

The requirement is to send a message to this specific URL

[image]

How would I get to read the actual Office 365 Connector URL so that I can use it in the $WEBHOOK_URL placeholder?

It is not an environmental variable, it is also unique per workspace, and I thus cant have a global variable.

Comment: Based on question's description it does not seem like a Microsoft Teams app development question. Could you please confirm if this is related to Teams app development? If yes, please share more details and repro steps of the issue.

Comment: Hi @Meghana-MSFT, correct - not a MS teams app development question, but rather a Jenkins question about using Teams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office 365 Connector plugin is designed to take care of the notification by itself according to your settings, and not for providing information for triggering custom notifications via bat or shell script. Therefore you cannot extract the information from the plugin configuration.

However if you do need the WebHook URL to send notification by yourself and still want to use the Office 365 Connector plugin, you can achieve it by defining a parameter for your job, like `WEBHOOK_URL`, give it the default value you currently have for the URL, and use it both in the Office 365 plugin and in the script.

[image]

Then use it like you did in the bat command and also in the Office 365 plugin:

[image]

Bonus: you can now also run the job with a different webhook for testing purposes.