# Jenkins - how to access parameter for Office 365 Connector (notification webhook)

Tags: powershell, jenkins, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

[image]

What is the variable for the Office 365 Connector (notification webhook)?

Other examples of variables that I am able to retrieve:

| variable | parameter |
| --- | --- |
| GIT_COMMIT | %GIT_COMMIT% |

Comment: I don't know a way to get these parameters, but you can send notification by script instead. This way you define all parameters in code: `office365ConnectorSend message: "#**Your Message**", status: "**${currentBuild.currentResult}**", color: "#AF0000", webhookUrl: "https://INSERT_YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL"`

Comment: Check out [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70607620/13110835)

Comment: @Peter - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved with above suggestions or still looking for any help?

Comment: Resolved with answer from @NoamHelmer thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer from comment section for more visibility.

The Office 365 Connector plugin is designed to take care of the notification by itself according to your settings, and not for providing information for triggering custom notifications via bat or shell script. Therefore you cannot extract the information from the plugin configuration.

However if you do need the WebHook URL to send notification by yourself and still want to use the Office 365 Connector plugin, you can achieve it by defining a parameter for your job, like `WEBHOOK_URL`, give it the default value you currently have for the URL, and use it both in the Office 365 plugin and in the script.

[image]

Then use it like you did in the bat command and also in the Office 365 plugin:

[image]

Bonus: you can now also run the job with a different webhook for testing purposes.